# Argument of type is not assignable error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm learning typescript (2.5.2). Could someone explain why the first call is ok but the second one gives error :

```
function printPerson(person: {firstName: string; lastName: string}): void{
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

let geo = {firstName: "geo", lastName: "porz", sex: "M"};
printPerson(geo); //OK here

// TS2345 Argument of type ... is not assignable to parameter of type ... 
printPerson({firstName: "geo", lastName: "porz", sex: "M"});
```

Comment: That's what typescript calls "fresh" objects, should look that up

Comment: thanks, this explain the tricky point
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537727/empty-interface-allow-any-object/42542804#42542804

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I think your question emerges because you use a Javascript coding style in Typescript. Coming from Javascript, you might be used to using constructs like `{foo:"bar"}` to pass data around. In Typescript, it really helps code readability if you declare the types of your variables, using `type` or `interface`.

```
interface Person { 
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

function printPerson(person: Person): void{
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}
```

Now, when creating a person object, instead of relying on type inference, we tell the compiler that `geo` is a Person:

```
let geo:Person = {firstName: "geo", lastName: "porz", sex: "M"};
```

Now you'll get that same error: you can't add the `sex` property to Person because it's not declared.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question being asked