# Type restrictions on function overloads behaves strangely

Tags: typescript, generics

I have these:

```
export interface ActionType<T = null> extends String {}

dispatch(type: ActionType<null>): ActionT<null>;
dispatch<TPayload>(type: ActionType<TPayload>, payload: TPayload): ActionT<TPayload>;
dispatch<TPayload>(action: ActionType<TPayload>, payload?: TPayload) { 
    // implementation
}

const TEST_ACTION: ActionType<string> = 'TEST_ACTION';
```

When I call this function with:

```
dispatch(TEST_ACTION)
```

I expected this not to not compile, because it requires there to be a payload. But it doesn't it picks the `dispatch(type: ActionType<null>): ActionT<null>;` overload, event though there is a `TPayload` and it's not `null`.

Is there a way to restrict the types even more?

link to playground example: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20ActionType%3CT%20%3D%20null%3E%20extends%20String%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ActionT%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Dispatcher%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch(type%3A%20ActionType%3Cnull%3E)%3A%20ActionT%3Cnull%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch%3CTPayload%3E(type%3A%20ActionType%3CTPayload%3E%2C%20payload%3A%20TPayload)%3A%20ActionT%3CTPayload%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dispatch%3CTPayload%3E(type%3A%20ActionType%3CTPayload%3E%2C%20payload%3F%3A%20TPayload)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('called')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ActionT%3CTPayload%3E()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20TEST_ACTION%3A%20ActionType%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20'TEST_ACTION'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Dispatcher().dispatch(TEST_ACTION)%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code contains very specific interface

```
export interface ActionType<T = null> extends String {}
```

ActionType is assignable to ActionType and ActionType is assignable to ActionType

```
let v1: ActionType<null> = 'v1';
let v2: ActionType<string> = 'v2';
v1 = v2; // no errors
v2 = v1; // no errors
```

so compler choose first from the signatures list: *dispatch(type: ActionType): ActionT;*. If you change interface like this

```
export interface ActionType<T = null> { val(): T; }
```

then conmpiler show error

> Argument of type 'ActionType' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'ActionType'.

See [Empty interface allow any object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537727/empty-interface-allow-any-object)

But if you want to assiciate actio names with action parameter type, use keyof feature.

```
// params
interface CreateUserAction { 
    name: string; 
    password: string; 
}

interface DeleteUseAction { 
    id: string; 
}

// params map
interface ActionMap { 
    'create': CreateUserAction;
    'delete': DeleteUseAction;  
}

// function
function dispatch<K extends keyof ActionMap>(type: K, actionParams: ActionMap[K]) { 
 //...   
}

dispatch('create', { name: 'hey', password: '1' });

// generic version
function dispatchG<TM, K extends keyof TM>(type: K, actionParams: TM[K]) { 
 //...   
}
```

Comment: when you add `val():T` you can't assign a string to action type anymore, because it doesn't have a `val` function.

Comment: Do you need to associate action names with type parameters? Like this "action1": Action1Options, "action2": Action2Option; where Action1Options, Acftion2Options are interfaces. Is it right?

Comment: Yeah, basically. But we have a lot of these, so I'm optimising the way you can write them. We used to write a class for each ActionType, but that's messy and difficult to maintain.