# How to create optional generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to create project structure where I can dynamically define interface, for different controller actions.

And, sometimes I want to make Query optional, or both optional. And accept only object-interfaces.

```
export interface Input<T, Q> {
  params: T,
  query: Q
}

export interface RestControllerAction {
  handler: (input?: Input<void, void>) => any | Promise<any>
}

interface MyParams {
  id: number
}
interface MyQuery {
  id: number
}

const action: RestControllerAction = {
  handler: ({params, query}: Input<MyParams, MyQuery>): void => {
    console.log('params', params)
    console.log('query', query)
  }
}

action.handler()
```

Can't compile it

```
Type '({ params, query }: Input<MyParams, MyQuery>) => void' is not assignable to type '(input?: Input<void, void> | undefined) => any'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'input' are incompatible.
    Type 'Input<void, void> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Input<MyParams, MyQuery>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Input<MyParams, MyQuery>'.
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSSTAFcYAeAFQBo4BFAPjgG8BYAKDjjEykwFsAzgC441dpwCOxNAE8RtdgF927UJFiIUaLLjgAlYAJgBhCCigQANpbQBBbDARnm4uAAtMSACY2oIgBTIJDAA-CKEwWQAbhAIXjQxcfQAlHAAvIyeMnAAPnAAChZ8CALAZFn0SipsyKgYOHgAsjL5PPwCLhyIXiJIxHwARmhVNVr1us200lDZrF1xvf1DUCPs2GZGcDiOZiIGRqbmVr72O0jpnZwe3r4BTNy8gjRSsorhRKRkza2PAjST0xkKREiS86UYc04nHWSAEVmAADpLBAAOb+ADkD3a6JoWMEyVc0I28KRqIxLxmOLgFJkBK6yjYDPY2ycSAR1x8aH8dOq7CAA)

I understand what this error means, but after reading docs and googling still can't understand how to force `Input<void, void>` accept different interfaces.

UPD1: [Link to playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEEsCcGcBdQFMAeBDAtgBwDZNALSgDqA9tANayhrUB2SSAJswLABQAZgK50DG8SKTqgAbmhyQmaeEgA8ABTTRMsADSgAityTQAngD4AFFmWqAXKCUqM60AEcd+y9t16AlKADeHUKD7CsKR4AHQ4pADmRgDkpjaw0Rpxqu6+-oHBSGGRMY5uiQ5OHhwAvhwckHSy0JxofPgAsnrWqgBqElIyQiJeoFKWdNwYAEa6oGXsldW19aBNrvrtktKCwt6gsEjKfAAWlgjQlRHj5eziyzLyTS22S52rdBrzRXcr3cZe-aAAjCUaXpttntQNEDtESp4QKBSBQOOd7ldmmZbh03sInnoFnpXl1hB8vr9-mg6HpSPAdrpkhhLKD4NBwZCwLpoOQAISnDhQgDKSACdCYyHQ2DwGgw5HwAWFkD4lyYHFQWHIiCmuhm+AASkgEABhYR04J4aAAQQE3W8aR2xKYhssimRdixxkqWG48EsXipsEsNzseWcWiKENAAF4DDQSaAAD5WFkYSCbOTEwylU4qmp1fAACSthu+PvWUOi2f5uZ90T61BYfBwymYoGGrtADFEY24myYIUIJB2egA-KAAJLRDCgNtHPqIUbhADunaMAHloBPQeleLIBbQaJJaL3Uuw-F9BiNdCnJlVVRnQMXrbpvliC2Aiznb1jy-HQFWa9A6w3EM3W+2nZEMQPb9kOI5jnQxyQJOSAznOi7LtQARrnWm4dDue5+IC0C7PsdJHKeHB8ggNCmsI3yWJqOp6iyOCGiaDwhua+6gMAABUg6cKAeCcMqdAuog04wTspCNmmao8ZAFD4FOpDThaz7QLa16lvaGiqS+RROgJrruJYoikFIIZhj4rEDqAwn0RsjDINALJLgARDcSDVCCzqum+Up8DBOB6KAlrUMSIJJuW8B6FgSCOWk7HAIpJa6CpSl5upV7JY6RgeW63iepYmnQCl8QaH6eh5elgb6WIRkCqGLF+H4JGZNkUSxPaBRZSEnpYfVjWhOELUle1unwCEJXdRMEwcHUDzfCEloJdARgeva7oEn8hRuO6OF4SCBxHOCQZQvOADSU3kXQs3zTei3LfEq1MJYABM60le6SZkhS0BUjSYIlIdYAAHLyaAnDkOk2CQIaSGgCdGi-oOgqRQIdbMmDn1IKcUIACo7DAAqoJguBIHDLIySIAQsDQiBXTaoCZcNe4KkqfTnumszUfAupVHRDHnY9dUBUpto+hoGVZe6uVWKlr0Bm4Qa1UmUYxqQcYJkmBhEWe0yXvlj35r0h5DKMS4TBJOtKY9969NtwJ7VBJzsMRgSINN3SPVRWqc7RBq6IxbvMWZfgcaAaRYxF+DRL0ks+gA3Bt-pYnHJRvvQZI0LAsCQBEdBoMMeCgPApAF+HIJRytaULXr9pxzLifjNEIRpPVoBh5F1CkNxWAspF0DhSCnrlrWLOSqYgh51kTfNy3JfRGWFZNmntCZ9nuf54XxeRSCutlo3rGxfF12WPTgkS+X2-S0UZWV1iEIGdVJkCw1GR9TkrXxENgmdfa3VP3QQQvwNIoH9XSjSKONTWIBXbCEenNJSS1JafAej8F6l9vA2x+gRKCB1PCcmAFAugMCaa6HgeXRBT0UGbW8O9cklJkQYPpH9dwQA)

UPD2 [Link to playground 3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&strict=true#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtKgQF0gJ2gQwMaQLABQqG2eoASpAM4oDCA9vCugwDZsYCCOKsTAHiKhQABSzosAW2oA1LG1gATLHyahIADzTwl1UAG8AvqAC8howBphoAIoBXDAE95ilWvgbtkXfuNmLS1AbACEGJRcFZVV+Ty0dPQsA42tCEXEnNgYsJVdojy8EvxNzFKIAPkMbAAdVAAsALlBadAQAcxspSBQ68KaAcgBxAFEAFX7QAB9QftEAeQBlcamZ0QBVZenZrlG6AAl+mzqsXU50JoAKBGr7FCaDGxFayRkAfibxF7ko91jUkREAEdHOgnO87CDIm4YkxHqAAEbhMFNMIRPK-Jj-AG1TLZJTgjJZHLomHwOFGACUZkqJycRCMRCIIFAw000mqnFAAEYiCRMLgkDwPFzPtJvtCCgZkEomvB7FJ4RhQAziMxSALQELYlyHM4SZLmpAJDhGs0WO1lYzCDgmLRQLhhU0qLRGMxWBxuLxYgItUwRRIxfq-pqvX7daCg5jAhZKqUavUBsBqqwlPZeMAGspgNQjegTf0sV0en0ZiNxljjqcMJcDM8xUFgc5KU0AG4MZTUqppAE2+DUdiQAB0WTaF36Du1g7rMgLoGn1ApcN7-c4w4Yo-HofgXMHjdBs73TkX3ZVKqIE79g8rSjOF1rAZk92UTS5VlAh-uOeNpv6LXa-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)

Comment: Why are you using `void` here?  Why are you defining generic parameters `T` and `Q` in your example and then not really using them? And `any | Promise<any>` is just `any`.  Could you pare this down to a [mcve] where there are no extraneous elements?  Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8vD9m)? Then I'd be happy to give a solution like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0ZrN).  If that works for you and you tighten up the example code, I'd be happy to write up an explanation; let me know.  If it doesn't meet your needs, please modify the example code to demonstrate exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Void is just attempt to give compiler know what "I want to put here any interface and you should consider it" Attached more detailed example to the post. Good remark about Promise<any>

Comment: The update only raises more questions, unfortunately: why are you defining `MyParamsValidation`, `Handler1Params`, and `Handler2Params` separately when they are identical to each other? TS's type system is [structural](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system); names don't matter.  The same goes for the `Query` types. `RestControllerAction` and `RestControllerAction2` are also identical, they just use different type parameter names.[more]

Comment: In  `RestControllerAction` you named the type parameters the same as existing types, this *shadows*, not *uses* these types (like `let foo = 123; function bar(foo) {}` does not use the same `foo` twice; the second `foo` shadows the first one inside `bar()`). I am looking for a *minimal* [mcve] that only does things directly related to your issue.  Otherwise the scope of the question is too nebulous for me to answer.  I originally thought you were just trying to deal with the problem where an optional *parameter* is not the same as an optional *property*, but now I'm not sure at all.  Help!

Comment: Thanks for your leading questions, I understood part of my mistakes and did something what can work in my project now. Did minimal reproducible example (attached to post again), but still don't understand why compiler don't check types as I expected. And I wanted to move generics from "RestControllerAction" to "handler" function level, but did not found way how to do it correctly.

Comment: Are you now asking why the empty type `{}` does not have [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)? If so, the question has changed to a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537727/empty-interface-allow-any-object) and we should close it.  Generally speaking a Stack Overflow post should ask a single question whose scope should not change over time; they are meant to be used like a FAQ; the chance that some future reader would find such topic changes useful is very low.