# IntelliJ does not hint error on return type mismatch in typescript

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, intellij-idea

We are developing a web application with react+typescript+spring boot with IntelliJ. Everything was fine until I noticed something that I did not expect. Consider this code snippet example:

```
export class TreeRefreshOutcome
{
}

export class TreeRefreshOutcome2
{
}

function foo() : TreeRefreshOutcome
{
    return new TreeRefreshOutcome2();
}
```

I expected, that the code inspection recognizes the type mismatch of the defined return-type of the function foo. The problem occurred while refactoring the code. There are currently no other marked errors in the codebase. I tried different combinations:

```
export class TreeRefreshOutcome
{
}
function foo() : string
{
    return new TreeFreshOutcome; //ERROR
}
```

```
export class TreeRefreshOutcome
{
}
function foo() : TreeRefreshOutcome
{
    return ""; //NO WARNING / ERROR
    return 5; //NO WARNING / ERROR
    return null; //ERROR
}
```

I switched from TSLint (that was the default in IntelliJ) to ESLint with no difference. It seems, that the problems rises with using a class as the defined return type. Using type definitions does raise errors as expected. Using interfaces behaves exactly like using classes. Other warnings and errors show up as I expected them to be. I am not that familiar with typescript nor JavaScript but I expected the IDE to recognize such simple errors.
Every hint to why this happens or what could possibly be wrong with some settings / configuration file might be appreciated.

Comment: TS uses structural equality, doesn't have nominal typing. The reason `TreeRefreshOutcome` and `TreeRefreshOutcome2` are considered the same is because both are empty interfaces, thus not different. See [Why do these empty classes behave strangely?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely)

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies it a bit. But type checking in typescript is a compile time thing. So imho this should be checked in the IDE - but comming from a hardly typed language this might be the price i have to pay.

Comment: "*But type checking in typescript is a compile time thing. So imho this should be checked in the IDE*" that's exactly what you've observed, though - you get a compile-time behaviour. And the explicit behaviour in regards to TypeScript is that it's a structural type system. See [the design goals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals). In your case there is literally no difference between `TreeRefreshOutcome` and `TreeRefreshOutcome2`. There is no real reason for substituting one for the other to be an issue. You get an when different: https://tsplay.dev/w21ZjW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty interface allow any object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537727/empty-interface-allow-any-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLAZ hinted me in the right direction. Thank you for that. I know, that the runtime does not distinguish between compile-time types. But in my opinion at least a warning should be raised from the IDE because the situation hints to a possibly wrong return type.

Answer: Empty class types are treated equaly at runtime **and compile** time.

Comment: "*Empty class types are treated equaly at runtime and compile time.*" is a confusing thing to say. At runtime empty classes are not treated any differently from classes that do have distinguishing characteristics. If you do `return new String()` that would work the same as `return new MutationObserver()` or whatever you wish. These are two incompatible classes, there is almost nothing in common between then other than what they inherit from `Object`. At runtime what they do or don't have in common doesn't matter, though.

Comment: Only thing that matters is how they are used `foo().toUpperCase()` won't work if `foo()` returns a MutationObserver. Similarly `foo().observe(document.body)` won't work if it returns a string. But that would only read to a runtime TypeError, it's not something inherently different because "the runtime" does anything with either of these to treat them the same or differently.

Comment: The compiler is the only thing actually does anything with types (and classes are declaring a class creates a shadow type to be used by the compiler). The compiler does treat empty types as equal because...they are. An empty glass is the same as any other empty glass. But you probably shouldn't be changing somebody's coffee to, say, vodka or vice versa. Because glasses filled with *something* are not interchangeable. See also: [Empty interface allow any object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42537727)